# Syncing a list from a DTO in EntityFramework

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, entity-framework-core

I have a Many-To-Many relationship between `User` and `Group`.

On of the operations in my API allows the client to update the `Groups` to which a `User` is member. The method is this:

```
public void UpdateUserMembership(int userId, IList<int> groupIds) 
{
    var user = dbContext.Users
                  .Include(u => u.Groups)
                  .First(u => u.Id == userId);

    var currentGroups = user.Groups;

    // TODO: Sync between the list of ids in groups and currentGroups

    dbContext.SaveChanges();
}
```

So the method **takes the ids of the groups** and **should update** `user.Groups` accordingly (adding or removing the groups, to adapt to the ids given)

How can I do it the right way? It's a common problem that I don't know how to handle :(

NOTICE: `user.Groups` is of type `UserGroup`, that is an "intermediate" entity between `User` and `Group` (many-to-many). It's like this:

```
class UserGroup 
{
    public int GroupId { get; set; }
    public int UserId { get; set; }
    public User User { get; set; }
    public Group Group { get; set; }
}
```

NOTICE 2: I'm using Entity Framework Core 2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly you can determine usergroup entities which will be inserted and deleted. Then you can perform database actions for these entities like this;

```
        public void UpdateUserMembership(int userId, IList<int> groupIds)
        {
            var user = dbContext.Users
                .Include(u => u.Groups)
                .First(u => u.Id == userId);

            var currentGroups = user.Groups;

            var groupsWhichWillDeleted = currentGroups.Where(x => !groupIds.Contains(x.GroupId)).ToList();
            var groupsWhichWillInserted = groupIds.Where(x => !currentGroups.Any(c => c.GroupId == x)).ToList();

            foreach (var deletedGroup in groupsWhichWillDeleted)
            {
                dbContext.UserGroups.Remove(deletedGroup);
            }
            foreach (var insertedGroupId in groupsWhichWillInserted)
            {
                var userGroup = new UserGroup { UserId = userId, GroupId = insertedGroupId };
                dbContext.UserGroups.Add(userGroup);
            }
            dbContext.SaveChanges();
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can take the differences between two list and save them to the table. I haven't tested, there may be innaccurate code.

```
public void UpdateUserMembership(int userId, IList<int> groupIds)
{
    var user = dbContext.Users
                  .Include(u => u.Groups)
                  .First(u => u.Id == userId);

    var diffIdList = groupIds.Except(user.Groups.SelectMany(x => x.GroupId)).ToList();

    foreach (var groupId in diffIdList)
    {
        var userGroup = new UserGroup { UserId = userId, GroupId = groupId };
        dbContext.UserGroups.Add(userGroup);
    }

    dbContext.SaveChanges();
}
```